# $A=\frac{6}{\frac{6}{\frac{6}{6-\cdots}-5}-5}-5 :A=\text{?}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$A=\cfrac 6 {\cfrac 6 {\cfrac 6 {6-\cdots}-5}-5}-5 :A=\text{?}$$
my try :

[image]

But I want to recurrence Sequence method!!

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{6}{a_n}-5: a_1=\text{?}$$

$$a_2=\frac 6 {a_1}-5,$$

$$a_3=\frac{6}{a_2}-5$$

???

thank you very much !

Comment: Try the recursion $a_{n+1} = \frac{6}{a_n} - 5$

Comment: @Winther. Continuation?!!

Comment: You could try to show that it converges for some suitable initial value(s) $a_0$?

Comment: @Winther. a_1 = ?

Answer (score 2):

$A=\dfrac{6}{A}-5\\A^2=6-5A\\A^2+5A-6=0\\(A-1)(A+6)=0\\A=1\text{ or }-6$